# Determine display mode of sharepoint page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have this question many times and bored while trying to find good solution. 
Dont understand why microsoft not include method which can easy determine mode of display page: "normal display" or in "design mode". 
It have many advices of check different variables, but it cant uniquely say that page in design on different type of page(webpart page and wiki page) and on postback or not.

Is finally tired me and i write this:

```
    public static bool IsDesignTime()
    {
        if (SPContext.Current.IsDesignTime) return true;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["DisplayMode"] != null)
            return true;

        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        if(page == null) return false;

        var inDesign = page.Request.Form["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"];
        var dispMode = page.Request.Form["MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName"];
        var wikiMode = page.Request.Form["_wikiPageMode"];
        var we = page.Request.Form["ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnWikiEdit"];

        if (inDesign == null & dispMode == null) return false; //normal display

        if (we == "edit") return true; //design on wiki pages

        if (page is WikiEditPage & page.IsPostBack & inDesign == "" & dispMode == "Browse" & wikiMode == "") return false; //display wiki on postback


        if (inDesign == "" & dispMode == "Browse" & (wikiMode == null | wikiMode == "")) return false; //postback in webpart pages in display mode

        if (inDesign == "0" & dispMode == "Browse") return false; //exiting design on webpart pages

        return true;
    }
```

Does anybody have better solution?

Comment: In Publishing pages accessing page.Request property fails with an exception. (HttpContext.Current.Request could be used instead.

Comment: For wiki pages, and only wiki pages, your code gave me the solution:  page.Request.Form["ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnWikiEdit"] == "edit". The FormMode takes care of non-wiki pages.

Answer (score 13):

you have 2 case to detect the page mode:

In case you are using a team site :

```
    if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
    {
        ltr.Text = "EditMode2";
    }
    else
    {
        ltr.Text = "ViewMode";
    }
```

in case you are using a publishing site:

```
if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Display)
  {
   // your code to support display mode
  }
  else // Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode = SPControlMode.Edit
  {
   // your code to support edit mode
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

if your work in WebpartPage than below code work for me

```
 WebPartManager mgr = this.WebPartManager;
 if (mgr.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.EditDisplayMode)
    {
        // logic when in Edit Mode
    }
 else
    {

    }
```

Comment: I came to this article with WebPartPage in mind.  This is a good start, this [SPTechBytes](http://sptechbytes.blogspot.com/2013/11/sharepoint-2013-handling-page-display.html) article shows the difference between the 3 main modes.

Comment: page.Request.Form["ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnWikiEdit"] == "edit" works for wiki pages. The above code works for non-wiki pages.

Answer (score 3):

I had a hard time getting any of these answers to work in Sharepoint 2013 given all the scenarios. I also couldn't get [EditModePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.editmodepanel(v=office.14).aspx) to work consistently. I found a snippet in [this article](http://platinumdogs.me/2012/10/10/sharepoint-detect-page-edit-or-design-mode-in-publishing-and-non-publishing-sites/) that seems to work in every scenario I've tried so far.

**Note:** This does not work in Page_Init but will work in Page_Load

```
var isPublishing = SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode != SPControlMode.Invalid;
var wpDMode = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page).DisplayMode.Name;
var isEditing = isPublishing
     ? SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode != SPControlMode.Display
     : (wpDMode.Equals("Edit") || wpDMode.Equals("Design"));
```

Then you can simply check `isEditing` for your conditions.

Answer (score 2):

please try this code ..

```
if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Display)
  {
   // your code to support display mode
  }
  else // Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode = SPControlMode.Edit
  {
   // your code to support edit mode
  }
```

Comment: Check this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24019/Switch-a-SharePoint-WebPart-page-display-mode-to-E

Answer (score 0):

**Handling SharePoint Page Modes.**

This works for me , I resolved my critical issue by using below lines.

```
if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
{
    alert.Text = "EditMode2";
}
else
{
    alert.Text = "ViewMode";
}
```