# Validation text box Visual Web Part SP2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have a basic form in a visual web part. I have a reguired field validator control to validate a text field see below for the actual setup:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="text-align:right;"><asp:Label ID="lblTopic" runat="server" Text="Topic: " CssClass="fld1"></asp:Label><span style="color:#E01237;">*</span></td>
<td valign="top" style="text-align:left;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtTopic" Width="250" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTopic" ErrorMessage="Please ensure you enter a topic before submitting!" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
</tr>
```

The issue I have is that when I add the web part into a page and then edit the web part settings to ammend the title, the validation seems to kick in meaning that I am then unable to exit the settings mode for the web part (i.e. the Apply and Ok buttons become unresponsive).

To get around this annoying issue I have to enter randon character in the text box for the validation to go away in order to be able to click on the OK button and exit editing mode and be abel to save the page.

Is there anything I can do stop the required field validator to kick in while in editing mode for the web part?

Is there a better simpler apprach to validate the text box?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET validator approach is legit in my opinion. 
I think a good solution will be to disable or hide the validator when page is in edit mode. Probably you'd want also to disable the submit button.

Refer to: [Determine display mode of sharepoint page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478913/determine-display-mode-of-sharepoint-page)